# commutative ring with infinitely many elements always a integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any counterexamples ? If not, how to prove it? 
thx
I have tried to assume there is a,b ≠ 0 and ab = 0 , then express other element in terms of a,b, but it seems doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you're confusing this with "a finite integral domain is a field"? For example, you can take $R[x]$ where $R$ is not an integral domain.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ for instance. Or any $R\times R$ where $R$ is a commutative ring.

Answer (score 2):

False.  Any direct product involving an infinite commutative ring, such as $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2$, is commutative and infinite, but not an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

There are also examples of commutative rings with zero divisors which are not product of rings. For instance, take any ring $R$ and pick a non trivial ideal $I\subset R$. Let $a$ and $b$ elements in $I$ which are not in $I^2$. Then
$$
\bar a\cdot\bar b=0
$$
In $R/I^2$ but $\bar a$, $\bar b\neq0$.